# How to make a "nested" translation string in Django template?

Tags: django, django-templates, internationalization

Here's a phrase I have to make translateable:

```
Poll ends in 2 hours 23 minutes
```

This string must have the main phrase and 'hour' and 'minute' in singular and plural forms.

```
{% blocktrans %}Poll ends in {{ poll.expire_hours }} ??? {{ poll.expire_minutes }} ???{% endblocktrans %}
```

What do I put then instead of `???` ?

---

Solution: made a simple tag that takes parameters like this:

```
{% readable_interval _('Poll ends in %s') poll.expire %}
```

and inside it converts the `poll.expire` (`timedelta`) into a readable text ('X days'/'N hours and M minutes'/'N hours'/'M minutes'/'Less than a minute'). All the strings that are coded in the tag code, are i18-ized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This type of string will bring you pain if you try to i18nize it this way. Write a [template tag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#howto-custom-template-tags) for it.

Comment: How the tag should look like and how the text in it can be translated?

Comment: The tag should take the hours and minutes, and it should use the normal Django i18n mechanisms.